# Repeat analysis on eukaryotic assemblies

Tags: assembly, repeat-elements, repeat

I have a hundred insect genomes and I'm looking for `repeated regions` along these `assemblies`.

First of all, I thought of using `RepeatModeler`, only the most familiar among you know that it is not at all optimized software that requires a lot of resources and calculation time, which is therefore not feasible in my case.

One possible solution `Repbase` is not free.

I thought for example to use a `blastn` approach by using in query the assemblages and in database of nucleotide databases containing **ETs**, which would be an approach maybe less sensitive but much faster! Only I can't find a database in ET representative of `eukaryotes`

I have two questions:

- Is there an alternative algorithm that is fast enough to process a large number of insect genomes?
- Is there a database of representative ETs to enable a `blastn` style solution?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: when you say "ET" do you mean "TE" ("transposable element")? If not, what does that abbreviation stand for?

Comment: Yes Transposable element sorry